# How to reuse the same process twice in within the same module in nextflow dsl2, but saving the output in a different name?

Tags: module, process, dsl, nextflow

i am building a nextflow workflow (DSL2) and within the same module i need to reuse the same process twice, but the syntax i am using seems to offend nextflow, in the sense that it complains that the process is already been used and i need to alias it properly, the thing is that i wouldn't know how.

Here is the error

`Process 'ReUsable' has been already used -- If you need to reuse the same component, include it with a different name or include it in a different workflow context`

and here a meaningful example:

```
process ReUsable {
    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/VF/SZ/${meta}", mode: 'copy', pattern: '*.out'
    container 'bla.1'
    input:
        tuple val(meta), path(input)
    output:
        tuple val(meta), path('one.out'), emit: out1
    script:
        """
        cat ${input} > one.out
        """
}
process ScndStep {
         publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/VF/${meta}", mode: 'copy', pattern: '*sub.out'
    container 'bla.2'
    input:
        tuple val(meta), path(out1)
    output:
        tuple val(meta), path('two.out'), emit: out2
    script:
        """
        sed -i "s/i/o/g" ${out1} > two.out
        """
}
workflow Unite {
      take:
               input
      main:
               out1 = ReUsable(input)
               out2 = ScndStep(out1)
               out3 = ReUsable(out2)
               .SaveAs{three.out}
      emit:
               out1
               out2
               out3

}
```

Clearly this is not the correct way, and when i looked a bit around it was recommended to set up a new module to then include the ReUsable twice each time with different name. It seems to me however to overcomplicating things. The whole point here is to make it light and reuse the same process within the same workflow, already having to rewrite a ReUsable2 process is off the scope.
Any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the simplest approach is to use the [`include`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-inclusion) keyword for this. Using [`module aliases`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-aliases) lets you reuse  components with the same name, for example:

Contents of `main.nf`:

```
include { ReUsable as ReUsable1 } from './modules/reusable'
include { ReUsable as ReUsable2 } from './modules/reusable'
include { ScndStep } from './modules/secondstep'


workflow Unite {

      take:
      input_ch

      main:
      input_ch | ReUsable1 | ScndStep | ReUsable2

      emit:
      ReUsable1.out
      ScndStep.out
      ReUsable2.out
}
```

Contents of `modules/reusable/main.nf`:

```
process ReUsable {

    input:
    tuple val(meta), path(input)

    output:
    tuple val(meta), path('one.out'), emit: out1

    script:
    """
    cat ${input} > one.out
    """
}
```

Contents of `modules/secondstep/main.nf`:

```
process ScndStep {

    input:
    tuple val(meta), path(out1)

    output:
    tuple val(meta), path('two.out'), emit: out2

    script:
    """
    sed "s/i/o/g" ${out1} > two.out
    """
}
```

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
params {

    publish_dir = './results'
}

process {

    withName: ReUsable1 {

        publishDir = [
            path: "${params.publish_dir}/ReUsable1",
            mode: 'copy',
        ]
    }

    withName: ScndStep {

        publishDir = [
            path: "${params.publish_dir}/ScndStep",
            mode: 'copy',
        ]
    }

    withName: ReUsable2 {

        publishDir = [
            path: "${params.publish_dir}/ReUsable2",
            mode: 'copy',
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Steve, that's very informative, and you confirm that there is no way i could do this via keeping the ReUsable process inside the main module (instead of making a module apart).
Also is there a way to keep publishDir inside the main module, without outsourcing it to the config file? what is the advantage in outsourcing it as you did? 
Many many thanks!

Comment: @user19232471 I don't think there is because ScndStep takes its input from the ReUsable process. The ScndStep process would need to be invoked before we can access the output to feed into the ReUsable process. Moving directives like publishDir to a config file would let the user easily override them if desired. The above config could be moved into a separate config file and included in your _nextflow.config_ using the [`includeConfig`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-include) keyword for example.